Executable size increasing dramatically
If I compile the following with g++ -g a.cpp, I get an executable of size 100,100 bytes. OK.
// content of a.cpp
#include <string>

std::string  m_name_a;

int main() { return 0; }

But when I add another file g++ -g a.cpp b.cpp:
// content of b.cpp
#include <string>

std::string  m_name_b;

The executable size is 135,00 bytes.
Why an increase of 35k?

I'm guessing the debug information is added for  header twice. can this be avoided?

It's hard to say, but the probable reason is that debugging information is being included for both source files, with some duplication.  Debugging information is usually omitted (e.g. by not specifying -g, or by stripping it out later) in production builds, so size of debugging information is usually not a concern at all when seeking to minimise executable size -  so little or no effort has not been applied to implementing compiler functionality that attempts to reduce or minimise the size of debugging information.

In addition to debugging information, C++ is not primarily designed for "Hello World"-oneliners. There is some overhead in the startup machinery that might not get optimized out even if it's not used.

What happens if you add a third file with the same content as b.cpp? And what happens if you omit the -g switch?

You can explore sizes of sections in executable with objdump. Try to enable at least minimal optimization with -Og.
